# onclick html and jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with my jQuery and html code, when I click in the `<a>` element that contains the `onclick` event nothing happens.

This is the html code

```
<a href='http://gomusic.designerbh.com/profile/bar_53d6af107ee03/'>Cabana</a>
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='actus("actuevent_53d6e48c65b68")' style='float:right;width:24px;height:12px;background:url(http://gomusic.designerbh.com/img/arrow.png) no-repeat bottom center'></a>
<span style='float:right;color:#ccc;margin:0px 10px 0px 0px'>49 Minutes ago</span>
<div class='actusevent_53d6e48c65b68' style='z-index:1;position:absolute;width:200px;padding:10px;background:#fff;margin:10px 0px 0px 260px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:5px'>content here</div>
```

This is the JS code, when I use this code nothing happens

```
function actus(b){
    $(".actus"+b).hide();
}
```

But when I do this the code alerts the value 122 and works fine

```
function actus(b){
    alert('122');
}
```

I already debugged it. I'm using the latest version of Chrome and jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="actusactuevent_53d6e48c65b68"`? I don't see one in the HTML.

Comment: it's a class i've change the code above sorry! but is till doesn't work

Comment: You don't have that as a class name, either. The function adds `actus` at the beginning of the argument.

Comment: You realize there's a typo, you didn't spell the classname and the name in the function the same ?

Comment: You want -> `onclick='actus("event_53d6e48c65b68")' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have wrong select javascript, try

```
function actus(b){
            $(".actus"+b).hide();
        }

  onclick='actus("event_53d6e48c65b68")'
```

Comment: friend i've change it but still doesn't work it doesn't return me anything

Comment: @MarcosBrinner Your class name begins with `actusevent`, the argument to the function begins with `actuevent` (no `s`).

Comment: $(".actus"+b).hide(); i'm using but nothing

Comment: There's no `class="actusactuevent_53d6e48c65b68"` in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar it worked to me,  what happens is that i'm passing the "actus['idhere']" in the function but i have just  to pass the id "event_53d6e48c65b68" thanks some times we don't see what we are doing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If the code you posted is different from what you're actually doing, how can we help you fix the real code?

Comment: this is the correct  code function actus(b){$(".actus"+b).hide();}   class='actusevent_53d6e48c65b68'  onmouseover='actus("event_53d6e48c65b68")'

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter value is different from the name of your class.

Note `onclick='actus("actuevent_53d6e48c65b68")'`and `class='actusevent_53d6e48c65b68'`.

Another thing: the element you're trying to get in `actus()` would certainly not match your parameter value. i suggest you change your parameter value to start with "event_" instead of "actuevent_", or you can change the prefix of the element in `actus()` to be: `$(".actusevent_")`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
To Barmars comment below - you could simply split it:

```
function actus(b){
    var i = b.split('_');
    $(".actusevent_"+b[1]).hide();
}
```

---

Look at your class name, it includes an underscore - `_`. What you want is this:

```
function actus(b){
    $(".actusevent_"+b).hide();
}
```

---

Errors:

- You're trying to call `$('.actus' + b).hide()` when your class is actually called `actusevent`.
- You're also missing the `_` in your jQuery function. So it won't ever work.

There are more efficient ways of doing this. If you have control over how you create your DOM elements, you could create something like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' id="my-link" data-actus-event='53d6e48c65b68' style='float:right;width:24px;height:12px;background:url(http://gomusic.designerbh.com/img/arrow.png) no-repeat bottom center'></a>
```

Now create your bind:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#my-link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var actusevent = $(this).data('actus-event');

    $('.actusevent_' + actusevent).hide();
});
```

Comment: That will look for `class="actusevent_actuevent_53d6e48c65b68"`.

Comment: @Barmar apologies, didn't look at that at all! Will update now

Comment: Darren I don't  need a split but you code looks fine as @Barmar said in the answer i repeat the value "actus" in the reference and the value pass by the function i remove the value of function and it worked fine